# switiching in fragments generating error

Tags: android

i am writing a program on fragments where i have one fragment in potrait mode and two fragments in landscape mode.
mainfrag1 contains one fragment in portrait and two fragments in landscape mode.
fr1 and fr2 are ids of fragment 1 and fragment 2
when i switch activity from portrait to landscape and as per the code below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainfrag1);
        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        try
        {
        f2=(Fragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fr2);

        }catch(Exception ep){}
        if(f2!=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "it is both", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             et=(EditText)f2.getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "it is only one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The check f2!=null returns true when we shift back from landscape to portrait but f2.getView returns null.
why f2 is not giving null when it is not on screen and how can i update the code to make it run properly
kindly clear on this.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

A retained fragment may not have it view at creation. The Fragment get through a own lifecycle similar to the Activity lifecycle, so it will be destroyed and then created again at the properly time.

But, if you are trying to get a specific View from a Fragment you have a design error, you should let the Fragment handle it actions itself.

Comment: how can i edit my code to not retain the fragment or let it handle its view creation so that it does not return null.but since the fragment referred to is not showing on screen can we still obtain a reference to its view

Comment: Do not try to findViewById at your Activity, add all Listeners at onCreateView in your Fragment